# Matlab Double cast from Uint64

Tags: matlab, floating-point, fixed-point

I am casting a 64bit fixed point number to floating point.  How should that be done in Matlab?  The following code gives different results.  What is the difference between typecast and the double(x)

```
temp = 2^32*uint64(MSB) + uint64(LSB);
out_0(1, 1) = typecast(temp, 'double');
out_1(1, 1) = double(temp);
```

An Example:

```
temp = 4618350711997530112

data = typecast(temp, 'double')

data =

    5.9194

>> double(temp)

ans =

    4.6184e+18
```

Comment: I get the same using typecast or double!

Comment: @emanbap  You need to make sure that temp is uint64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to maintain the same number, you should definitely use [`double`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) to convert it:

> **`double`** Convert to double precision. 
>   `double(X)` returns the double precision value for `X`.

Whereas [`typecast`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/typecast.html) maintains the *internal* representation, i.e. the bytes are maintained the same but or differently interpreted:

> **typecast** Convert datatypes without changing underlying data.
>       `Y = typecast(X, DATATYPE)` convert X to DATATYPE.  If DATATYPE has
>       fewer bits than the class of X, Y will have more elements than X.  If
>       DATATYPE has more bits than the class of X, Y will have fewer
>       elements than X.

Note that it is only possible to use `typecast` when the number of bytes are the same, which is not true for `double` as it tries to represent the same number as close as possible in double precision. For example, you cannot typecast `uint32` to `double`, but you can typecast two `uint32` to one `double` number. If you use `double` to convert it, you will obtain respectively one and two doubles.

**C++ equivalent**

`X = double(uint64(123));` 
 => `int64_t x = 123; double X = x;`

`X = typecast(uint64(123), 'double')`  
 => `int64_t x = 123; double X = reinterpret_cast<double>(x);`

Comment: or `double(x)` is the same as `static_cast<double>(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, because it seems you have two 32-bit uint values `MSB` and `LSB`; To convert them to uint 64 you can use typecast.

```
U = typecast([MSB,LSB],'uint64')
```

Then conversion to double as suggested by m7913d

```
D = double(U)
```

So you see `typecast` has a very different function compared to `double`.